# CreateArchive[] without directory copy

Tags: files-and-directories, compression

```
CreateArchive["C:\\temp out\\"]
```

The above creates a zip file containing directory `temp out` at level 1, but I require just the files at the first level.  Consequently I have to use this:

```
Run["powershell.exe Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\\temp out\\*' -DestinationPath 'C:\\temp out.zip'"]
```

Is there a way to use `CreateArchive` to produce a zip with the files at level 1?

Comment: That is the same question, right? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160977/5478

Comment: @Kuba Yes, pretty much the same.